# geometric methods in number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was given this problem but I have no idea how to prove it. Any ideas?

Let $n$ be a positive integer. The number of positive integral solutions to $\frac{1}{n}$ = $\frac{1}{x}$ + $\frac{1}{y}$ is $\tau(n^2)$ where $\tau(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$.

Answer (score 6):

We set out to show that the equation $\frac{1}{n} = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{y}$ (for nonzero $n$, $x$, and $y$) is equivalent to $(x-n)(y-n)=n^2$:

Multiply by $nxy$ to get $xy=ny+nx$. Add $n^2$ to both sides and subtract $nx+ny$ from both sides to get $xy-nx-ny+n^2=n^2$. Then the LHS can be factored, yielding $(x-n)(y-n)=n^2$ as claimed. Now you just need to reason about what positive integer values of $x$ and $y$ are possible.

Comment: im struggling to do that. How do you do it?

Comment: @Chris see my edit. Note also that I changed $(n-x)(n-y)$ to $(x-n)(y-n)$, which makes a little more sense contextually.

Comment: Another way of doing this - and a natural way of arguing from scratch, is to note that both fractions on the right-hand side are positive, so each is less than $\frac 1n$ and $x,y\gt n$. So set $a=x-n, b=y-n$. Then $\frac 1n=\frac 1{a+n}+\frac 1{b+n}$ and clearing fractions gives $(a+n)(b+n)=n(b+n)+n(a+n)$ which reduces to $ab=n^2$ and $a$ can be chosen to be any positive factor of $n$.

Comment: @MarkBennet nice! I probably did something similar to that when I first stumbled on this solution years ago.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the equation.

$$\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$$

If the square lay on multipliers.  $n^2=ks$

Then the solution can be written.

$$x=n+s$$

$$y=n+k$$

Although in the General case can be any character.   Though it is necessary to mention another solution.

For the equation:  $$\frac{1}{X}+\frac{1}{Y}=\frac{1}{A}$$

You can write a simple solution if the number on the decomposition factors as follows:  $$A=(k-t)(k+t)$$

then:  $$X=2k(k+t)$$  $$Y=2k(k-t)$$  or:  $$X=2t(k-t)$$  $$Y=-2t(k+t)$$

Although these formulas give one and the same solution.