# Find the number of ordered pairs of positive integers (x, y) that satisfy the equation (1/x) +(1/y)= 1/2004.

Tags: combinatorics, inverse

after some simplification, we get (2004y)/(y-2004)=x 
and by looking at the prime factorization of 2004 we observe there are only 12 ways in which 2004 can be expressed as the product of two integers.
which gives us 12 ordered pairs.But the answer is 45. how?(sorry for not using mathjax my browser does not support it)

Comment: The title says 2014 and the body 2004 - which is it?

Comment: oops sorry its 2004

Comment: [A generic version](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/403036/11619). And [another](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1180699/11619), and [yet another](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/868324/11619). The problem is nice, but it's a repeat.

Comment: What has this to do wih `linear-algebra`?

Comment: We also have an earlier version of this occurring [in a contest from 1995](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/580601/11619). To the uninitiated, contest organizers often use the year of the contest as a "random integer generator".

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos That is a good question. My theory is that in some places a course on linear algebra may have material that elsewhere would appear in a first course on abstract algebra or yet another course. Of course, it is also possible that askers simply pick any familiar sounding tag, but I'm sure regional variation also plays a role.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Of course it is a good question. I just don't see why it is classified as a Linear Algebra question.

Comment: I'm sorry for the "linear algebra" tag

Comment: it is no longer there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guide:

Once we get $$2004y+2004x=xy$$
$$-2004y-2004x+xy=0$$
$$2004^2-2004y-2004x+xy=2004^2$$
$$(2004-x)(2004-y)=2004^2=2^4\cdot 3^2\cdot 167^2$$

Can you complete the task?

Comment: thank you everyone

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}= \frac{1}{2004}$$
Rearrange: 
$(x-2004)(y-2004)=2004^2 = 2^4\cdot3^2\cdot167^2$. 
There are exactly $5\cdot 3\cdot 3= 45$ positive integer divisors of this number, so it has $90$ integer divisors. This yields 90 solutions. 
For example, one case is that $x-2004= -2^3\cdot3$, and then $y-2004=-2\cdot3\cdot167^2$. Note that however you write $2^4\cdot3^2\cdot167^2$ as a product of two integers, it yields exactly one solution. So the answer is $90$.

Answer (score 1):

1/x +1/y=2004

y+x/xy = 1/2004

2004(x+y)=xy

0=xy-2004x-2004y

0=(x-2004)(y-2004)-(2004)^2

(2004)^2=(x-2004)(y-2004)

It should be pretty easy from here. Just find the factors of 2004 squared.